# Python. Как обратиться к свойству дочернего класса из родительского?

Tags: python, ооп

Есть следующий минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
class ParentClass():
    def do(self):
        print("Здесь вывести значение experiment_id")

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, experiment_id):
        self.experiment_id = experiment_id
        print(experiment_id)

objChild = ChildClass("...")

objParent = ParentClass()
objParent.do()
```

Все, что нужно - это обратиться к свойству `experient_id` дочернего класса (`ChildClass`) из родительского (`ParentClass`).Такое вообще возможно? Можно, конечно, перенести метод `do` непосредственно в класс `ChildClass` и просто создавать его экземпляр через

```
objParent = ParentClass()
objParent.do()
```

но в классе `ChildClass` в оригинале создатся окно с помощью PyQt5 и конструктор по-этому не должен запускаться более одного раза.

Как решить проблему?

**UPD:** Нашел вот такой вариант решения:

```
class ParentClass():
    def do(self, child_obj):
        print("Здесь вывести значение experiment_id")
        print(child_obj.experiment_id)

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, experiment_id):
        self.experiment_id = experiment_id
        print(experiment_id)

objChild = ChildClass("...")

objParent = ParentClass()
objParent.do(objChild)
```

Comment: Ничего не понял, при чём тут конструктор вообще и с какого перепуга он будет запускаться более одного раза?

Comment: И да, в самом первом примере вы создаёте два отдельных никак не связанных объекта `objChild` и `objParent`, и внутри `objParent` естественно не будет никакого `experiment_id`, что делает всю ситуацию ещё более непонятной

Comment: @andreymal конструктор рисует окно, а метод `do()` должен выполняться многократно. Если я пренесу его из `ParentClass` в `ChildClass` и буду постояноо создавать экземпляр этого класса, то получу множество окон...

Comment: А зачем вы будете постоянно создавать экземпляр этого класса? Что-то непонятное у вас происходит

Comment: Кроме того, ваш UPD создаёт подозрение, что наследование вам на самом деле вообще не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
class ParentClass():

    def do(self):
        print(f"Здесь вывести значение experiment_id: {self.experiment_id}")


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, experiment_id):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.experiment_id = experiment_id
        print(f'class ChildClass(ParentClass):        {self.experiment_id}') 

objChild = ChildClass("Привет ...")
objChild.do()                                                            # <----
print("\n===========================")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, вы изменили пример без понимания намерений автора, а во-вторых, вы сломали ParentClass и любой линтер больно надаёт по рукам за такое

Comment: @andreymal я ничего не менял и не ломал и не надо меня бить по рукам, просто напишите свой вариант ответа, и все.

Comment: Если вы ничего не меняли, то где `objParent` в вашем коде?

Comment: Ну и про "не ломал" врать не надо: `ParentClass().do()`